# Running git commands through php in a browser

Tags: php, git, browser

Edit: I managed to get this working by printing out stderr via proc_open() then debugging with the information that was there.

This is my first SO question so my apologies if it's not in the correct format.

I'm trying to run the following commands via php in my browser:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -a -m "commit message 01"
```

The url of the page is 
    localhost/jbrowse/testingphp/phpInsteadOfPerl.php

I have tried the following in my scripts:
passthru(), shell_exec(), exec(), system()

```
############using passthru############
passthru('git init');
passthru('git add *');
passthru('git commit -a -m "commit message 01"');
```

Prints this to the browser:
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jbrowse/testingphp/.git/

```
############using shell_exec()############
$one = shell_exec('git init');
$two = shell_exec('git add *');
$three = shell_exec('git commit -a -m "commit message 01"');
echo "$one";
echo "$two";
echo "$three";
```

Prints this to the browser:
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jbrowse/testingphp/.git/

```
############using exec()############
$one = exec('git init', $oneOutput, $oneReturn);
$two = exec('git add *', $twoOutput, $twoReturn);
$three = exec('git commit -a -m "commit message 01"', $threeOutput, $threeReturn);
echo "one: $one";
echo "two: $two";
echo "three: $three";
echo "<br>";

echo "oneOutput: ";
echo join($oneOutput);

echo "twoOutput: ";
echo join($twoOutput);

echo "threeOutput: ";
echo join($threeOutput);
echo "<br>";

echo "oneReturn: $oneReturn ";
echo "twoReturn: $twoReturn ";
echo "threeReturn: $threeReturn ";
```

Gives:
one: Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jbrowse/testingphp/.git/two: three:

oneOutput: Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jbrowse/testingphp/.git/twoOutput: threeOutput:

oneReturn: 0 twoReturn: 0 threeReturn: 128

128, according to the following link, means "Invalid argument to exit" http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html

```
############using system()############
system('git init');
system('git add *');
system('git commit -a -m "commit message 01"');
```

Gives:
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Library/WebServer/Documents/jbrowse/testingphp/.git/

If i run these php scripts from my terminal, all of the git commands execute perfectly.

I thought it might be a permission problems so I've given all users complete permissions on everything in the /testingphp and the /.git folder. (Of course the .git folder's permissions go back to default when reinitialised, however if i take out the git init sections of the code then it still doesn't work.)

The permissions on all of the files and directories are as follows:
(test001.sh is a shell script which i put the git commands in and tried calling that through php.)

```
la-mckiernan:testingphp robertmckiernan$ ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx   5 robertmckiernan  wheel   170  6 May 14:45 .
drwxr-xrwx  24 robertmckiernan  wheel   816  6 May 13:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx  13 robertmckiernan  wheel   442  7 May 10:28 .git
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 robertmckiernan  wheel  2628  7 May 10:28 phpInsteadOfPerl.php
-rwxrwxrwx   1 robertmckiernan  wheel    75  6 May 15:25 test001.sh

la-mckiernan:.git robertmckiernan$ ls -al
total 40
drwxrwxrwx  13 robertmckiernan  wheel   442  7 May 10:28 .
drwxrwxrwx   5 robertmckiernan  wheel   170  6 May 14:45 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 robertmckiernan  wheel     6  6 May 16:50 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rwxrwxrwx   1 robertmckiernan  wheel    23  6 May 14:45 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx   2 _www             wheel    68  6 May 16:34 branches
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www             wheel   137  7 May 10:28 config
-rwxrwxrwx   1 robertmckiernan  wheel    73  6 May 14:45 description
drwxrwxrwx  11 robertmckiernan  wheel   374  6 May 14:45 hooks
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www             wheel   214  7 May 10:28 index
drwxrwxrwx   3 robertmckiernan  wheel   102  6 May 14:45 info
drwxrwxrwx   4 robertmckiernan  wheel   136  6 May 14:45 logs
drwxrwxrwx  44 robertmckiernan  wheel  1496  7 May 10:27 objects
drwxrwxrwx   4 robertmckiernan  wheel   136  6 May 14:45 refs
```

I'm using mac OSX mavericks.

Comment: Why don't you use a library like this: https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php